# How to fix JNI crash on env->NewObject()?

Tags: android, crash, java-native-interface, zip

Here is my program:

```
extern "C" {        
 JNIEXPORT jint Java_android_app_integrity_VerifyIntegrity_checkCrc(JNIEnv *jniEnv,jobject thiz,jstring crcStr) {

    jclass clsZipFile = jniEnv->FindClass("java/util/zip/ZipFile");
    jmethodID mtdConstruct = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clsZipFile, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jmethodID mtdGetEntry = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clsZipFile,"getEntry","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;");
    jclass clsZipEntry = jniEnv->FindClass("java/util/zip/ZipEntry");
    jmethodID mtdGetCrc = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clsZipEntry,"getCrc","()L");
    LOGD("pos2");

    jobject objZipFile = jniEnv->NewObject(clsZipFile,mtdConstruct,crcStr);
    if (NULL == objZipFile){
        LOGD("NULL == objZipFile");
    }

    LOGD("pos3");
    jobject objZipEntry = jniEnv->CallObjectMethod(objZipFile, mtdGetEntry,"classes.dex");
    LOGD("pos4");
    jlong ret = jniEnv->CallLongMethod(objZipEntry, mtdGetCrc);

    LOGD("%ld",(long int)ret);
    return 0;
}
};
```

It only print "pos2". The line below the "LOGD("pos2");" will cause crash!
I can't find the reason. Who can help me? Thx!

Comment: just curious-  why would you do this?  You're passing a java string down to C and then using it only o make a java object-  just do that on the java side and pass down the jobject to avoid some JNI pain.  In fact there's no good reason for any of this to be done in C at all.  You won't even get a speed boost.

Comment: You need more error-checking. *Every* JNI API that you call can silently fail. Clearly either the class lookup or the constructor lookup is failing. And why are you coding this in JNI at all? It's one line of Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing the following line. It has an invalid signature and will cause an implicit exception to be thrown for MethodNotFound exception and is likely the culprit.

```
jmethodID mtdGetCrc = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clsZipEntry,"getCrc","()L");
```

Should be:

```
jmethodID mtdGetCrc = jniEnv->GetMethodID(clsZipEntry,"getCrc","()J");
```

However I would second other suggestions to check return values from all FindClass and FindMethod calls as they not only return NULL they also each throw an exception upon failure. Also OutOfMemoryException is thrown when JNI can not allocate a local reference object to return for your jclass lookups.